# virtual directory created in classic mode getting 500.24 error

Tags: asp.net, iis, integrated-pipeline-mode

virtual directory created in  iis in Classic Mode. but when i try to access i getting HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error An Asp.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode

Comment: I don't think "Classic Mode" (whatever that is) makes this into asp-classic.